# How to draw the scale meter/ ruler for the 3D model in WebGL

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d, webgl

I want to draw a fixed horizontal line (or a ruler) that gives info about size/distance or zooming factor like the one in Google Maps ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hazb1.png)).

Here is the another example with different zoom levels and camera used is orthographic

[image]

I try to implement the same with perspective camera but I would not able do it correctly

Below is the result I am getting with  perspective camera

[image]

The logic that i am using to draw the ruler is

```
var rect = myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var canvasWidth = rect.right - rect.left;
var canvasHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
var Canvas2D_ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");


// logic to calculate the rulerwidth
var distance = getDistance(camera.position, model.center);
canvasWidth > canvasHeight && (distance *= canvasWidth / canvasHeight);
var a = 1 / 3 * distance,
l = Math.log(a) / Math.LN10,
l = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(l)),
a = Math.floor(a / l) * l;
var rulerWidth = a / h;
var text = 1E5 <= a ? a.toExponential(3) : 1E3 <= a ? a.toFixed(0) : 100 <= a ? a.toFixed(1) : 10 <= a ? a.toFixed(2) : 1 <= a ? a.toFixed(3) : .01 <= a ? a.toFixed(4) : a.toExponential(3);
    
    
    
    
Canvas2D_ctx.lineCap =  "round";
Canvas2D_ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
Canvas2D_ctx.textAlign = "start";
Canvas2D_ctx.font = "12px Sans-Serif";
Canvas2D_ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';
Canvas2D_ctx.lineWidth = 0;

var m = canvasWidth * 0.01;
var n = canvasHeight - 50;
Canvas2D_ctx.beginPath();
Canvas2D_ctx.moveTo(m, n);
n += 12;
Canvas2D_ctx.lineTo(m, n);
m += canvasWidth * rulerWidth;
Canvas2D_ctx.lineTo(m, n);
n -= 12;
Canvas2D_ctx.lineTo(m, n);
Canvas2D_ctx.stroke();

Canvas2D_ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';
Canvas2D_ctx.fillText(text + "  ( m )", (m) /2 , n + 6)
```

Can any one help me ( logic to calculate the ruler Width) in fixing this issue and to render the scale meter / ruler correctly for both perspective and orthographic camera.

Comment: Perspective will always behave differently. A "100m" part close to the camera will appear smaller when rendered further away. So you can't simply have a "100m" ruler drawn in the corner. and expect it to apply for all objects in a Perspective view.

Comment: @TheJim01 thanks for the comments. Now i understood that. But for orthographic view it should work without any issue. I don't have any idea on how to implement it in orthographic view.Can you help me in this.

Comment: I think you should probably re-word your question to match your new requirements. It seems like you already know how to draw the ruler, but I'm not exactly sure what more you're asking for.